# In a Java EE project, after deleting my classes, I can't get them back?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, compilation

I have deleted the contents of my folders WEB-INF/classes under my Eclipse Java EE project. Now that it is emtpy, I can't get them back. Refreshing the project doesn't do anything.

Is there some way I can re-compile my classes again and get them back into this folder?

Answer (score 3):

Which view are you using?  By default, Eclipse won't show you these classes in the "Package Explorer" view, for example - but will in the "Navigator" view.  So they may actually be there, and you just don't see them.

Otherwise, just try rebuilding your project, using the options available from the "Project" menu.

Comment: I look them from file manager, there are no any files there. Simultaneously, there is some content in server's WEB-INF/classes and this content is recovering if I delete it.

Comment: Your Eclipse configuration may not necessarily match what is on the server.  Right-click on the project, click "Properties", then select "Java Build Path" from the left-hand navigation.  What is shown for the "Default output folder" - as well as any source-folder-specific "Outout folders"?

Comment: Globally it is that classes folder. And how to see source-specific output?

Comment: In the same dialog - above "default output folder", below "Source folders on build path".  Each source folder should have a "Output folder" listed - next to Includex/Excluded/Native library location.

Comment: Ah yes found them. But they wera all defaulted to global.

Comment: As long as your project is building, you should see *.class files generate here.  Make sure Project / "Build Automatically" is set - or run a manual build.  Also try using Project / Clean...  If this still doesn't help, we'll probably need to see more of your Eclipse project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick which can actually help you if you remember your class names.
If you deleted something and you will create a file with this same name you can click on this file in your package explorer and chose "compare with the local history" option. it has helped me a few times.